# Delete a document with Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to delete a document in Kibana, and if so, then how?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what Kibana is for, but it seems like such a useful feature :) Right now I have to search, copy the document id, go to Sense and make the query, and then repeat this for each document I want to remove.

Maybe there's a plugin for Kibana that let's me do this sort of thing? I have tried Googling and searching here, but I must be using the wrong terms, or no one else is wondering the same thing.

Comment: It's not possible directly from Kibana, which is mainly a visualization tool. It's definitely possible to create a plugin to help you do it, though, but I don't know any existing plugins that does it so far, except the Sense plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing Kibana source code is the most straightforward way. However it will be hard to maintain with new releases.

Another way is to build a small API that get index, type and id of a document and then call the DELETE on the Rest API of ElasticSearch. You can then build url in Kibana using a field which is a copy of the document id. 
[image: Kibana field delete]

Comment: Alright, thanks. Changing the source code seems like it will lead to future headaches with upgrades, so I'll look into building some sort of plugin or extension if it becomes worth the trouble.

Comment: I know this is old, but how would this work if you need to use a custom HTTP request method (DELETE)?

Answer (score 10):

Go to Kibana DevTools and Execute delete request:

```
DELETE IndexName/DocType/DocId
{}
```

[Sample screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40RyD.png)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned was the workaround I was using at the time. I guess "Sense" changed name to "DevTools". Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

No

Kibana doesn't have such feature and as I know, no plug-in exist.

I suggest that you edit Kibana's source code and add remove button.
Kibana is Open Source (Apache License, Version 2.0), So change it and simply add a button for removing documents or ...

I modified my Kibaba several time, it's simple